# Strategy to auto update database on new app version deploy

Tags: database, deployment

We have an JavaEE web application running with Maven to do the build process, JSF 2.2, Tomcat 7 as our server and MySQL 5.5 as our database. With the development of new features, sometimes we need to change our database structure. At this moment we have the work to do all this manually:

1. Wait until we have no clients online (around midnight)
2. Go to Tomcat manager
3. Undeploy context
4. Deploy new context
5. Go to phpMyAdmin and execute the SQL scripts

While our application is still "small" is still viable to do this process, but we are looking forward to automatize this. We already know about Jenkins, that can read our Git, build the .war using Maven and - not sure yet - do the deploy at Tomcat.

But I am not sure about how we will automatize our SQL scripts to execute when we deploy a new version. It needs to be robust, so it doesn't mess with our database, by for example, running it twice or something like that.

My question is if there is a better deployment process focusing on database changes that can help me.

Comment: Asking for tool or framework recommendations is explicitly off-topic for StackOverflow. Please see the [help] for more information.

Comment: Might be a good idea. If the question gets closed or you get too many downvotes, it can sometimes impact your ability to ask future questions.

Comment: @Lexi I can't delete the question, I will try to rewrite my question a better way. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to append the previous answer about liquibase, you could use the [flywaydb](https://flywaydb.org/) too.

Answer (score 0):

There are solutions for this out there. One of them is called [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use liquibase to apply incremental database changes along with jenkins to automate build process.